# Windows 7 ProgramData permission denied despite being admin

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions

I've tried to install Skype today, started the installer as admin etc.
but then comes up with an error saying

> You do not have permission to access C:\ProgramData\

despite being logged in as admin.

Things I've tried so far that haven't worked:

- Take Ownership reg script
- Setting Owner to myself
- Setting Owner to everyone
- allowing full control for Users (which then comes up with: "An error occured while applying security information to: C:\ProgramData The access control list (ACL) structure is invalid)
- booting into safemode and installing that way
- turning UAC off
- unchecking 'read-only' (apparently I do not have the permissions to do so)
- adding another Admin account and taking ownership of ProgramData but still it doesn't work

I am the sole user on the computer and have disabled most homegroup features.